# Show that if F is a finite field, then $F^F=P_F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The hint is: Let F has as elements $a_1,...,a_n$. Note that if $$f_i(x)=c(x-a_1)...(x-a_{i-1})(x-a_{i+1})...(x-a_n)$$, then $f_i(a_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$ and the value $f_i(a_j)$ can be controlled by the choice of $c\in F$. Use this to show that every function on F is a polynomial function.

First, I need to construct a polynomial $p(x) \in F[x]$ such that $p_i(a_i)\neg 0$ and $p_i(a_j)= 0$ When $i\neq j$ and explain why such a polynomial exists.

Next I think I need to show for all $a\in F$ that f(a)=p(a).

Using Fraleigh’s seventh edition of A First Course in Abstract Algebra. Need help with problem 22.31c. I’m completely lost. Thank you!

Comment: You already asked the question on April 30th.

Comment: Read about Lagrange's Interpolation Formula which uses polynomials very closely related to the $f_i(x)$ that you have.  Use this to construct a _polynomial_ $g(x)$ with the property that $g(a_i) = b_i, i = 1,2,\ldots, n$  for any specified  set of elements $b_1, b_2, \ldots b_n$. The collection of $n^n$ such polynomials $g(x)$ represents all the $n^n$ functions from $F$ to $F$.